# Convert HTML pages to PDF, but after applying ublock origin filters

Tags: pdf, conversion, html, ublock-origin, wkhtmltopdf

I want to convert a bunch of webpages to PDF using wkhtmltopdf. But I want the uBlock Origin personal filtering under My Filters (currently being used in my browser) be applied on each HTML page.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can't as wkhtmltopdf does not support browser addons.

Comment: did you found a solution for you?